Bathtub is moving away from tile and wall or was it always like this?
https://imgur.com/a/qyxiIwt
I bought the house in April. The seller remodeled in 2015 but I'm unsure when he put the tub in. I've noticed that this has occurred in the last few months. Previously, there was caulk and I notice the caulk has crumbled. Why is this happening? Is this something I can fix myself or do I need a professional?

A picture from farther away. showing all of the tub and a description of the type of construction of your house would help here.  The tub appears to have moved to create a gap, but there is no telling why from the pics.

No, that was not always like that.  The tub has pulled away from the tile.  Without more pics, it's impossible to speculate in an educated fashion on why that might be.  Does anything look wrong on the back side of the tub?
